# Where are the game files for DMP mod so I can put them on my second machine as well

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've got two computers and I'd like to move the game files from my one computer to my other so I can play under the same multiplayer account using the DMP mod.

Can anyone point me to which files I should move to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the GAMEDATA/DMP folder, that should contain all information about the plugin to the other computer.

Answer (score 0):

Most Steam games work if you copy the entire folder, I don't see why Kerbal would be an exception to that. I would just copy all the files. The best way to do it would be to delete the local content through Steam, then copy the entire folder from the other computer and pick install in Steam. It will install from the copied files and have everything identical to the other PC.